# Schedule Invokation of functions with arguments to the event loop

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

how would you invoke a function (called func in my code) with arguments as part of the event_loop?
considering these functions should be invoked multiple times upon server incoming requests.

```
async def my_func_1(json_message: dict, writer: StreamWriter) -> bool:
    return True

async def my_func_2(json_message: dict, writer: StreamWriter) -> bool:
    return True

async def my_func_3(json_message: dict, writer: StreamWriter) -> bool:
    return True

switcher = {
    "Forward": my_func_1,
    "Backward": my_func_2,
    "Up": my_func_3
}

async def dispatcher(reader: StreamReader, writer: StreamWriter):
    try:
        msg = await reader.readline()
        message = ujson.decode(msg.decode())
    except Exception:
        print("unable to parse json from read stream:" + str(msg.decode()))
    
    if "method" in message:
        func = switcher.get(message['method'], UnknownMethod)
        # how would you invoke func with arguments as part of the event_loop?
        # considering these functions should be invoked multiple times.

def init():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    coro = asyncio.start_server(dispatcher, '127.0.0.1', 666, loop=loop)
    server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)
    
    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    # Close the server
    server.close()
    loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
    loop.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    init()
```

Thanks for all the help

Comment: You would call `func(argument_1, argument_2)`.  It isn't clear what those arguments would be though.

Comment: @FiddleStix You are close to but since __func__ will be an `async` function you must call it with `await`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my understanding of your question, the answer is to simply call the function with the desired parameter as you would in any other context.

```py
# ...
if "method" in message:
    func = switcher.get(message['method'], UnknownMethod)
    await func(message, writer)
# ...
```

Comment: You are correct, I guess this is the outcome of covid19 + extra workhours :)
BTW, this is just one of the problems I've fixed today in my code... not perfect but working :) thanks!